# Android Pie 9 Crash When Using Media Player

Tags: java, android

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
>
> - I already test out with other Android Version and it does not have problem when using media player.

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_play);

play=findViewById(R.id.play);


play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainPlay.this, R.raw.click);
        mediaPlayer.start();

});
```

Comment: `MediaPlayer.create` is returning `null`. Check your logcat to see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before start media player please check once is not equal null (!=nu)
Like bellow

```
play=findViewById(R.id.play);

mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainPlay.this, R.raw.click);
play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(mediaPlayer!=null)
           mediaPlayer.start();

});
```

Or I suggest initializing media player outside of click because you are trying to access media player immediately may be reason  get null

Comment: yap I already add it. Thanks bro.Is there because the audio is the problem?? Because I have other audio and it is working .